# Include stock information in WooCommerce order confirmation email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

On a WordPress 5.6 website with WooCommerce 4.9/Storefront, I've modified my child theme's functions.php to display an estimated shipping date in the products description, as well as in the cart and order page, based on the product *get_stock_quantity()* and *is_on_backorder()* functions.

I have trouble doing the same in the order confirmation email, apparently because by the time I use these functions, the stock has already been decreased.

For now, the code looks like this, based on an [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564232/add-the-product-description-to-woocommerce-email-notifications):

```
// Setting the email_is as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'the_email_id_as_a_global', 1, 4);
function the_email_id_as_a_global($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'order_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
function order_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text = false ) {
    // Getting the email ID global variable
    $refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
    $email_id = $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'];

    // If empty email ID we exit
    if(empty($email_id)) return;

    if ( 'customer_processing_order' == $email_id || 'new_order' == $email_id || 'customer_on_hold_order' == $email_id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );

        echo '<div style="color:#378cbd"><p>' . estimated_shipping_date_message( $product ) . '</p></div>';
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I should insert here the code for the estimated_shipping_date_message() function. It basically echoes a date whether the product is in stock or not.

I'm looking for any pointers on how to tackle this issue. Please tell me if more info is needed here.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Maybe you could store the is / isn't in stock, or the estimated delivery calculation in order meta in an earlier hook to use here? (But I'm not a WooCommerce expert.)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It's better than what I came up with: if the email needs to be re-sent later on, the information will be consistent. It's a bit hard for me to figure out, though. Instead, I modified my estimated_shipping_date_message() function to take the stock quantity as argument and I pass it this sum as value: $product->get_stock_quantity() + $item->get_quantity(). This way I obtain the former stock quantity, and the calculation stays good as long as the product stock quantity is not modified again, for instance by a new order.